# Two classes with one class having a pointer to another class

Tags: c++, class, object-oriented-analysis

(C++) Suppose I have two classes A and B. Class B has a pointer to class A along with a method. How exactly do I interpret what's going on in this case. When that method is called does it have access to the methods in Class A since it's pointing to a possible instance of A

```
Class A {
public:
void method1() const;
void method2() const;
}
Class B {
public:
A* method3(int);
void method4();
void method5();
}
```

Let me know if I'm being vague here or need to provide more info

Edit 1: So basically Class B creates objects that get stored in a map that is accessible by an integer key. Class A has methods that can manipulate any one of those individual objects. So I guess in this case method3() would take in the key of the map as input and then it fetches that object from the map and then the user can choose to do method1 or method2 from Class A to manipulate it. 
i.e. The object being stored in the map could be like a game piece and the methods in Class A can like flip it or rotate it.

Comment: "pointer to class A" - it's just a return type of `method3()`. can you add more info?

Comment: Added a few more details in the Edit.

Comment: Returning a reference to, or a copy of, the object in the map would be more usual.  If it's a pointer you don't know whether it could be null, and whether you need to delete it

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just try it?

```
class A {
public:
   void method1() const;
   void method2() const;
}

class B {
public:
    A *GetA(int i) { return &mapA[i];
    void method3();
private:
    std::map<int, A> mapA;
}


int main()
{
   B b;
   auto pA = b.Get(1);
   pA->method1();
   return 0;
}
```

As long as A has a default constructor, this should create new items in B's map if they don't exist.

Note that making class A method1 and method2 const means that they don't change anything in A, so they couldn't be functions which change any of A's state.

Comment: Oh woops my bad only one of them should be a constant

Answer (score 0):

The member function `A* method3(int)` is going to return a pointer to an instance of the class `A`. Thus the compiler will reserve a proper amount of memory for it on the heap. Most probably you will need to create dynamically an instance of that class inside the function `method3` and return the pointer pointing to it.